# Sum over algebraic numbers

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

Consider the set $A = \{a : \sum_{n=0}^m c_n a^n =0 \}$, for some m, Where the coefficients are any sequence of rational numbers (i.e the set of algebraic numbers).
Does there exist a function, $f$ such that
$$\sum_{a \in A} f(a) < \infty$$
Excluding trivial examples such as the 0 function.

I tried constructing one as such:
Let $f(x)$ be defined by saying$$\begin{cases} x^2 & 0\leq x \leq 1(A^*) \\ \frac{1}{x^2} & 1\leq x (A^+) \end{cases} $$

So $$\sum_{a \in A} f(a) = \sum_{a \in A^*} a^2 + \sum_{a \in A^+} \frac{1}{a^2}$$
But surly $$\sum_{a \in A^*} a^2 + \sum_{a \in A^+} \frac{1}{a^2}<\int_{0}^{1} x^2 \,dx + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \,dx =\frac{4}{3}$$ which would mean the sum converges.

But $$\frac{4}{3} < \frac{\pi ^2}{6} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Which implies what is (to me) a paradoxial result $$\sum_{a \in A^+} \frac{1}{a^2} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}.$$
Would this mean that $$\sum_{a \in A^+ - \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{a^2} < 0?$$

Regardless, does anyone have any input?

NOTE: $A$ is countable.

Comment: Do you want the function to be natural, in some sense?

Comment: If by natural, then you mean without the forced construction that I attempted, then yes. But ultimately, I'm curious to know whether it exists or not.

Comment: Yes one exists, however you won't be able to realize it via some "piecewise continuous function."

Comment: The inequality where you go from countable sum to integral, is invalid. Your sums are $+\infty$. Just in a very small interval around $1$ there is a countable "amount" of numbers where $f$ is really close to $1$, say over $0.5$, and it alone brings the sum to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is countable, so there exists a bijection $\,\varphi : A \to \mathbb{N}\,$. Let $g$ be any function such that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n \ge 1} g(n)$ converges absolutely, and let $f(a) = g(\varphi(a))$, then $\,\displaystyle \sum_{a \in A} f(a)\,$ converges absolutely, and  in fact $\,\displaystyle \sum_{a \in A} f(a) = \sum_{n \ge 1} g(n)\,$ because absolutely convergent series [can be arbitrarily rearranged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence#Rearrangements_and_unconditional_convergence).

Comment: +1. Good answer, but for most of people existence is not enough.

Comment: But this is a boring answer because you immediately forget the structure of $A$ and just "keep" its cardinality. But of course this is the easiest answer, so relevant enough. But it would be more interesting with a more natural $f$ that depended somehow on properties of the algebraic numbers.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen The above answers this part "*ultimately, I'm curious to know whether it exists or not*" of the question.

Comment: I understand. This definitely answers the question I asked, but didn't quite give me what I was looking for.

Comment: What this does tell us though, is that there are an infinitude of functions that converge. Let $g(n) = x^-n$.

Comment: @RyanGoulden Indeed. As for an explicit form of such a function, you can assume WLOG that $c_k$ are integers, then define something like $\,f(a)=1 / \left( p_1^{c_0} p_2^{c_1} \ldots p_m^{c_m} p_{m+1}^k\right)^2\,$ with $\,k\,$ being the index of $a$ in an enumeration of the $m$ roots. Then it's easy to show that $f$ is injective, and the convergence follows.